# Find $x$ such that $1-2 x+4 \frac{x^{2}}{2 !}-8 \frac{x^{3}}{3 !}+16 \frac{x^{4}}{4 !}-...=2$.

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I converted the series in this form:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}2^{n}}{n !}x^n. $$

So: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}2^{n}}{n !}x^n=2.$$

Or: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^{n}}{n !}x^n=2.$$

I know the series resembles the Taylor function for $e^x$, but I am not sure how I can use it.

The formula for Taylor series centered at $0$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n !}x^n$ so I think I might have to do something about $f^{(n)}(0)=(-2)^n$?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you see that your series is the Maclaurin series of $e^{-2x}$? Just replace $x$ by $-2x$ in the familiar series for $e^x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-2)^nx^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-2x)^n}{n!}=e^{-2x},$$

so your equation becomes

$$e^{-2x}=2,$$

which has solution $x=-\frac{\ln(2)}{2}$.

Comment: We could have given some time to the OP to figure out the details themself.

Comment: Sure, but then again I would assume OP has taken their time trying to solve it before posting the problem. OP had already made the connection to the exponential function's Taylor series, so what I showed was merely a small step really, in recognizing that it was $e^{-2x}$. I have full faith in OP being able to do the rest after there themselves though.